# One Custom post type 404's others don't

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error

I've created 7 custom post types and all but one works. I don't even know where to go from here. I've flushed my permalink structure, and that didn't work. The following code is the array that I'm passing to my custom post type construction function:

```
<?php
require('CustomPostTypes.php');
require('CustomPostTaxonomies.php');
require('SaveCustomPosts.php');
function createposts(){
    $PostList = array('Jobs'                    =>array('plural'    =>'Jobs',
                                                        'singular'  =>'Job',
                                                        'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag','Departments')),
                      'Display Products'    =>array('plural'    =>'Display Products',
                                                        'singular'  =>'Display Products',
                                                        'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag','display-types')),
                      'Partners'                =>array('plural'    =>'Partners',
                                                        'singular'  =>'Partner',
                                                        'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag','partner-types')),
                      'Events'                  =>array('plural'    =>'Events',
                                                        'singular'  =>'Event',
                                                        'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag','event-types')),
                      'Product Profiles'        =>array('plural'    =>'Product Profiles',
                                                        'singular'  =>'Product Profile',
                                                        //'hierarchical' => true,
                                                       //'exclude-from-search' => true,
                                                       ),
                      'Service Reports'         =>array('plural'    =>'Service Reports',
                                                        'singular'  =>'Service Report',
                                                       'exclude-from-search'=>true,),
                      'Intake Damage Report'    =>array('plural'    =>'Damage Reports',
                                                        'singular'  =>'Damage Report',
                                                        'exclude-from-search'=>true,));
    
    add_custom_posts($PostList);
}
```

And this is the code that I'm using to create the custom post types:

```
<?php

function add_custom_posts($PostList){
    foreach($PostList as $PostType){
        if(isset($PostType['singular'])){
            $PostSingular = $PostType['singular'];
        } else {
            $PostSingular = '';
        }
        if(isset($PostType['plural'])){
            $PostPlural = $PostType['plural'];
        }else{
            $PostPlural = '';
        }
        if(isset($PostType['hierarchical'])){
            $Hierarchical = true;
        }else{
            $Hierarchical = false;
        }
        if(isset($PostType['parent'])){
            $Parent = $PostType['parent'];
        }else{
            $Parent = '';
        }
        if(isset($PostType['taxonomies'])){
            $Taxonomies = $PostType['taxonomies'];
        }else{
            $Taxonomies = '';
        }
        if(isset($PostType['exclude_from_search'])){
            $ExcludeFromSearch = $PostType['exclude_from_search'];
        }else{
            $ExcludeFromSearch = false;
        }
        custom_post_type($PostSingular,$PostPlural,$Hierarchical,$Parent,$Taxonomies,$ExcludeFromSearch);
    }
}

function custom_post_type($PostSingular,$PostPlural,$Hierarchical,$Parent,$Taxonomies,$ExcludeFromSearch) {

    $PostLabels = array(
        'name'                  => __( $PostPlural),
        'singular_name'         => __( $PostSingular),
        'menu_name'             => __( $PostPlural),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent '.$PostSingular),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All '.$PostPlural),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View '.$PostSingular),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New '.$PostSingular),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add '.$PostSingular),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit '.$PostSingular),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update '.$PostSingular),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search '.$PostPlural),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not Found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash'),
    );
    
    $PostArgs = array(
        'label'                 => __( $PostPlural),
        'description'           => __( $PostPlural),
        'labels'                => $PostLabels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        'hierarchical'          => $Hierarchical,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => $ExcludeFromSearch,
        'yarpp_support'         => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'position'              => 5,

    );
    if($Hierarchical === true){
        $PostArgs['rewrite'] = array('slug'=>str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($PostPlural)),'with_front' => false,);
        array_push($PostArgs['supports'],'page-attributes');
    }
    if($Parent !== ''){
        $PostLabels['parent_item'] = 'Parent ' . str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($Parent));
        $PostLabels['parent_item_colon'] = 'Parent ' . str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($Parent)) . ':';
    }
    if($Taxonomies !== ''){
        $PostArgs['taxonomies']= $Taxonomies;
    }
    register_post_type(str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($PostPlural)), $PostArgs );
}
```

The custom post in question should be sitting at the following URL, but it keeps returning a 404 error:

[www.example-domain.com/product-profiles/%product-profile%](http://www.example-domain.com/product-profiles/%product-profile%)

All of the other custom post types resolve correctly and there's nothing in the debug log. As such, I'm completely lost as to how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I still have no idea what was going on. I had to disable the custom post type and drop all references to the 'product-profiles' entries that I had created from the wp_posts table manually, including autodrafts and revisions. After that I was able to re-enable the 'product-profile' post type and it ended up working
If anyone has any insight as to what caused this, please chime in.